# Highcharts wordcloud : how to eliminate words based on their weight

Tags: arrays, charts, highcharts, tags, cloud

I need to eliminate words based on their weight. I tried to use word.weight before arr.push to avoid that words with weight lower than 3 goes into array ... but this doesn't work !

```
<script>
    lines = text.replace(/[():'?0-9]+/g, '').split(/[,\. ]+/g),
    data = lines.reduce((arr, word) => {
        let obj = Highcharts.find(arr, obj => obj.name === word);
        if (obj) {
            obj.weight += 1;
        } else {
            obj = {
                name: word,
                weight: 1
            };
            
            if(word.weight> 3) {
                
                    arr.push(obj);
                  
            }

        }
        return arr;
    }, []);
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code won't be able to push a single element into array because you only push when the element is not yet contained in the array. But in that case, you create an `obj` with weight 1, which won't be pushed, because of your `weight > 3` condition. I'd suggest to push all words to the array and then filter out those with a weight of 3 or less

Furthermore `word` in you case is a `string` and a string doesn't have a `weight` property. You probably meant checking `if (obj.weight > 3)` instead ...

```
<script>
    lines = text.replace(/[():'?0-9]+/g, '').split(/[,\. ]+/g),
    data = lines.reduce((arr, word) => {
        let obj = Highcharts.find(arr, obj => obj.name === word);
        if (obj) {
            obj.weight += 1;
        } else {
            obj = {
                name: word,
                weight: 1
            };
            arr.push(obj);
        }
        return arr;
    }, []).filter(x => x.weight > 3);
</script>
```